# gnuplot 4.7 hypertext not working with canvas terminal

Tags: html, canvas, gnuplot, mouseover

I am using gnuplot 4.7 patch 0.

My data file "test.txt" looks like the following:

```
0  0  net0
1  1  net1
2  2  net2
3  3  net3
4  5  net4_outlier
5  5  net5
```

My gnuplot code "script.gp" looks like this:

```
set term canvas
set termoption enhanced
set label at 0,0 "Origin"
set title 'mouse over points'
plot 'test.txt' using 1:2:3 with labels hypertext point pt 7 ps var lc rgb "black"
```

Testing:

I tested that canvas is an available terminal by typing terminal and canvas is available in the list. The version of firefox I am using is "Mozilla Firefox 5.0". I have checked that this version is compatible with html 5 canvas element.

I am running the script as:

```
gnuplot script.gp > canvas.html
```

I am loading the output html file as:

```
firefox canvas.html&
```

Result:

I get a plot, with the 10 points, but the hover label is not working. If I remove hypertext and use normal label, then that is working - labels are printed.

Could someone point out what is the mistake I am making here - I have read that hypertext is supported in gnuplot 4.7 patch 0.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Hi Christoph, I see you have edited the formatting, you are the exact person I was looking for/trying to contact, for help with the above issue..I read your previous solution that you provided on a similar question - but doesnt seem to work for me while experimenting..

Comment: :) You'll get an answer in two minutes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `hypertext` feature is connected to the `mousing` terminal option, i.e. use

```
set terminal canvas enhanced mousing
```

to see the labels on mouse over.

If you don't want the additional coordinate box, then you must just replace the line

```
<script type="text/javascript">gnuplot.init = function() {};</script>
```

in the html `<header>` with

```
<script src="/absolute/path/to/js/gnuplot_mouse.js"></script>
```

of course with the correct path to the javascript file (see the path to `gnuplot_common.js`).

As note: 4.7 is a development version with no patchlevel. Soon, the new stable version 5.0 will appear.